# What are kviews?

Tags: support

I occasionally come across certain questions on math.SE where the sidebar lists kviews. See below for an example. I searched for kviews on meta, but could not find a similar question. If this is in the FAQ, I apologize.

[image: Example of kviews]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A *kilo view*, with the usual prefix meaning *a thousand*.

Comment: I did not notice this before: *If you hover over the number, there is a tooltip with the exact number of views.* See: [What are “kviews”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55109/what-are-kviews) at meta.SO.

Comment: Thank you Mariano. Should I delete this question as it is a duplicate then?

Comment: Just a thought- does the software allow for *mviews*, *gviews*, ... as well?

Comment: @PeterPhipps it does. See [this list on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A500000&submit=search)

Comment: Floating point notation (sans the point) would be better: 2e3 views, 4e5 views, etc. Takes the same three characters, does not require neologisms, and works up to 9e9, which is 9000 times the record number of views on SO so far.

Comment: @LVK, maybe you could suggest that at meta.SO ... :)